# How to return error message from MVC Web API that returns a Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api, model

I have this method

```
[HttpPost]
public ContactModel Contact() 
{
// validation contact must have at least first name
 if (contactModel.firstName == null)
    return null;                           // This works fine

 /*
 if (contactModel.firstName == null)
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please provide first name");                 // it gives error


// insert to database
}
```

So, how do I indicate to user to provide at least first name. I thought of adding some header to response, but that is not user friendly.

I also added

```
if (contactModel.firstName == null) 
{
    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please provide first name");          // this doesn't do any good either.
    return null;                           // This works fine
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateErrorResponse` returns a `HttpResponseMessage` which cannot be cast to `ContactModel`. You want to throw a `HttpResponseException` instead and add the error using `CreateErrorResponse`

```
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
    "Please provide first name"));
```

This will return HTTP 400 (Bad Request) with the following json:

```
{"Message":"Please provide first name"}
```